# Converting sqlite3.cursor to int PYTHON

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, bottle

I am trying to return an INT 'id' from a particular table in my database when i try this

```
retrieveID = "SELECT id FROM posts WHERE usernick=?"
latestPost = cursor.execute(retrieveID,(usernick, ))
if latestPost:
    return latestPost
else:
    return None
```

I return

```
AssertionError: <class 'int'> != <class 'sqlite3.Cursor'> error
```

I am trying to test it against a webtest.

I have also tried the

```
int(cursor.execute(retrieveID, (usernick,))
```

But I am unable to convert the cursor to an in. I was wondering if there is a way to do so and if there isn't how do I go about fixing this issue

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to get an element from the cursor first,
e.g.

```
cursor.execute(...)
post_id = cursor.fetchone()[0]
```

or use `cursor.fetchall()` if there are many rows for that query

```
cursor.execute(...)
for row in cursor.fetchall():
    post_id = row[0]
```

Comment: Thank you so much :) can you just answer me one thing ? the "cursor.fetchone()[0]" what does the '[0]' represent?

Comment: You can see it as one row containing many columns, so you're reading the first column of the row as returned by the query (your query only returns one column)